# Pass Parameters to JavaScript Function From Generated HTML

Tags: javascript

I have an AJAX program which gets data from the website and posts the info to Facebook. My problem is quite simple. I need to generate HTML in the callback function. Here is a button:

```
var city = "Beijing";
html+= "<td><input type=button value=FACEBOOK onclick=\"fb("+city+")\"></td>";
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = html;
```

Say I have the variable "city", and it has certain value. By generating the button like above, I cannot pass the city to the function fb(city). It even wouldn't invoke that function. However, it works if I remove the parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var city = "Beijing";
html+= "<td><input type=button value=FACEBOOK onclick=\"fb('"+city+"')\"></td>";
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = html;
```

you forgot SINGLE QUOTES :).

**NOT fb("+city+") than generates fb(Beijing)**

**BUT fb('"+city+"') than generates fb('Beijing').**

Answer (score 1):

when you functions get processed, Since city will be replaced as "Beijing", the html fragment will be generated like:

```
<td><input type=button value=FACEBOOK onclick="fb(Beijing)"></td>
```

As you can see here, Beijing doesn't have a "" around it. So it will be treated as a variable and which doesn't really exist.

The simplest fix might be :

```
html+= "<td><input type=button value=FACEBOOK onclick=\"fb('" + city + "')\"></td>";
```

Actually there are many other better ways to achieve your purpose. And you should bind the 'click' event from a javascript code rather than add it inline in html. And by binding it from a javascript function, actually you can embed the value in a closure.

Comment: Ming, do you have an example of the closure? I think that might be worth documenting. Then the op can decide which technique to use.  :)

Comment: +1 - I think this is great advice. When you keep your JavaScript out of your HTML and your HTML out of your JavaScript, the result is much more maintainable code.

Answer (score 0):

The string within a string within a string technique is something you'll eventually outgrow. A better technique is to use the onclick property to assign the click event:

```
var city = "Beijing";
var td = document.createElement("td");
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.setAttribute("type","button");
input.setAttribute("value","FACEBOOK");
input.onclick = function() {
    fb(city);
};

td.appendChild(input);
document.getElementById("myDiv").appendChild(td);
```

Not only does this eliminate the unreadability of strings within strings, but it also ensures that the DOM nodes you add to your #myDiv element will be recognized by JavaScript in the DOM. Some browsers have trouble programmatically recognizing DOM elements that are added using innerHTML. I've experienced that behavior in Firefox and XUL-based browsers.

As an aside, jQuery can perform this operation a lot smoother and guarantees cross-browser compatibility, but that's a question for the `jQuery` tag.